# My panel has same link for each page

Tags: jmeter

Is it possible to set up the following scenario using JMeter?

For my web site i have set same link for every page and it is working fine for.but i am trying to test performance of this by using JMETER , jmeter provide no result to me, it is possible to record such type of script with the help of jmeter.

your response will be very help full to me.

Thanks.

Comment: yes i have already tried this but each time only log in page is visible  to me

Comment: This may be a bit trivial advise but you probably can to monitor traffic during sending requests / receiving responses (possibly different request params sent along with different requests), as well as correctly handle viewstates / session params / cookies (if any) - and then look how to implement this using jmeter. So you have to imagine the complete interaction schema first.